# Getting the info from the password protected http. Java

Tags: java, http, windows-server-2003, windows-server

I'm trying to get the file from the http in a simple java program.
I tried to use both domain username and a local one.
We are using Windows Server 2003.

I found 2 solutions to it. The first one is:

```
public class HttpTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://corp.domain.com/name/info.html");
            String userPassword = "user:password";
            String encoding = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(userPassword.getBytes());
            CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The other way I found is:

```
public class HttpTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                String prompt = getRequestingPrompt();
                String host = getRequestingHost();
                InetAddress addressIP = getRequestingSite();
                int port = getRequestingPort();
                String username = "user";
                String password = "password";

                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
            }
        });

            URL url = new URL("http://corp.domain.com/name/info.html");
            CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The first one throws the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://corp.domain.com/name/info.html
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1838)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
at httptest.HttpTest.main(HttpTest.java:51)
```

Line 51 points to :

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
```

The second one throws:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1846)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
at httptest.HttpTest.main(HttpTest.java:51)
```

Line 51 is the same.

Both login-password pairs (domain and local) work if I try to access the server from the browser.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your server is using Basic Authentication?  IIS has several modes:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825205(v=cs.10).aspx

Comment: I'm not. Because this is the first time I'm trying to do something like that.

Comment: Hmm..  Can you use a network inspector or something in the browser to see the actual headers sent by the browser?  Should be pretty easy to pull these from firefox or chrome

Comment: I checked with our IT guy. Integrated Windows authentication and Digest authentication for Windows domain servers are checked. Not the Basic authentication.

Comment: Is that what you are asking about?

Request: GET http://corp.domain.com/delorie.htm HTTP/1.0
HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 1656
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
WWW-Authenticate: Digest qop="auth",algorithm=MD5-sess,nonce="+Upgraded+v18bc06f81dbdfbe12faa0a4569e73cf01dfe89f5ae489730f04155ad6208eda8867f71e05a127aa4c37a568dca740f81b",charset=utf-8,realm="domain.local"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET 2.0
MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 5.0_Pub
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Proxy-support: Session-Based-Authentication
Connection: Proxy-support

Comment: Yep, you are using NTLM authentication, not basic authentication

Comment: Do you know how to fix the code in to make it work?

Comment: I've posted a path forward below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above, it looks like you are using NTLM authentication.  I would suggest using a library with native support for NTLM authentication.  This issue is discussed on this page:

[authenticate with ntlm (or kerberos) using java UrlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168526/authenticate-with-ntlm-or-kerberos-using-java-urlconnection)

Here's the page about NTLM on the Apache HttpClient site:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/ntlm.html